# How to create torrent file from magnet link using java?

Tags: java, bittorrent, torrent, magnet-uri

So I wanted to work on a new Java project that converts magnet URIs into .torrent files, however I can't find a way to do that, basically I broke a magnet URI into pieces :

The used URI :

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:d2474e86c95b19b8bcfdb92bc12c9d44667cfa36&dn=Leaves+of+Grass+by+Walt+Whitman.epub&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example4.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example5.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example3.com%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example2.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example1.com%3A1337
```

The breaking down :

> magnet:?
>
> xt=urn:btih:d2474e86c95b19b8bcfdb92bc12c9d44667cfa36
>
> dn=Leaves+of+Grass+by+Walt+Whitman.epub
>
> tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example4.com%3A80
>
> tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example5.com%3A80
>
> tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example3.com%3A6969
>
> tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example2.com%3A80
>
> tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.example1.com%3A1337

from what I gathered using [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#File_structure), The torrent file contains the files , lengths and paths of the required files but I can't seem to get that from the magnet URI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarsAtomic SHA-1 "encrypted"?

Comment: @MarsAtomic no, not really. Are you saying he should reverse a SHA-1 hash? And are you saying that without any hint of sarcasm?

Comment: I think so, I have found that the hashsums are SHA-1 encoded

Comment: Well, now you'll find out that hashes are one-way, meaning you can't "decode" them.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to recreate the .torrent file from the magnet link alone.

The way torrent clients gets the .torrent file from a magnet link is:

- Get a peer list from the tracker(s) and/or from the DHT.
- Connect to peers and download the .torrent metadata using
  [BEP9 - Extension for Peers to Send Metadata Files](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0009.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, okay so,let me rephrase my question, using Java , how can I connect to peers and get the meta data if I have the magnet link ?

Comment: Implementing the above means implementing a almost complete bittorrent client - i.e. it's most probably easier to find a way to use a existing, already finished client.

Comment: I have searched for already made torrent clients ( like [this one](https://github.com/atomashpolskiy/bt) ) , but it is too complicated for me to get the meta data grabbing part.

Comment: It is complicated and there is no way around that. As a alternative, you maybe can use a online service: http://btcache.me https://btso.pw https://itorrents.org http://magnet2torrent.me https://torrage.info https://thetorrent.org http://magnet2torrent.com

Answer (score -1):

not really clean but..

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c","start firefox "  + mag});`

// needs firefox and a default torrent handler.
// mag = magnet string