# dht find_node no response

Tags: java, udp, bittorrent, dht

I'm writing a dht server and meet some problem.
I send the *find_node* request to bootstraps, and they return me some compact node info(416bytes) which contains 16 nodes info
then i bdecode and store the ip address and port, continue send *find_node* request to these nodes,but i get no response.

Server code here(receive packet and start a new thread to add nodes to a list)

```
public void run() {

    try {
        while (true) {
            byte[] buffer_rcv = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer_rcv, buffer_rcv.length);
            socket.receive(recvPacket);
            System.out.println("get!!!");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        LinkedList<Node> nodes = BDecode.bdecode_find_node(recvPacket);
                        for (Node n : nodes) {
                            table.add_node(n);
                        }

                        System.out.println("table size" + table.get_all_nodes().size());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }).start();
            System.out.println("waiting new packet!!!!!!!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I download the jbittorrent api from sourceforge and use it to bdecode

```
public static LinkedList<Node> bdecode_find_node(DatagramPacket recvPacket) throws IOException {

    byte[]nodes_compact_info = (byte[]) ((Map) new BDecoder().decodeByteArray(recvPacket.getData()).get("r")).get("nodes");

    byte[]node_info = new byte[26];
    byte[]node_id = new byte[20];
    byte[]ip_byte = new byte[4];
    byte[]port_byte = new byte[2];
    int port;


    LinkedList<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<>();
    //System.out.println("nodes_compact_info.length"+nodes_compact_info.length);
    for (int i = 0;i<nodes_compact_info.length/26;i++) { //416 = 16 * 26byte_per_node 
        //0-19 id 20 21 22 23 ip 24 25 port

        node_info = Utils.subArray(nodes_compact_info, i*26, 26);           
        node_id=Utils.subArray(node_info, 0, 20);           
        ip_byte = Utils.subArray(node_info, 20, 4); 

        String ip = "";
        for (int j = 0;j<ip_byte.length;j++) {
            ip+=Utils.byteToUnsignedInt(node_info[j]);
            ip+=".";
        }
        ip = ip.substring(0, ip.length()-1);
        //System.out.println(ip);
        port_byte = Utils.subArray(node_info, 24, 2);
        port = Utils.byteArrayToInt(port_byte);

        nodes.add(new Node(node_id, ip, port, new Date()));         
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Finally i send *find_node* request to every node in list

```
public void get_neighbor() {

    ArrayList<Node> nodes = table.get_all_nodes();
    System.out.println("*********get_neighbor!!!");

    for (Node n : nodes) {
        try {

            byte[] find_node_query = BEncode.find_node(this.id, this.id);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(find_node_query, find_node_query.length,
                    InetAddress.getByName(n.getIp()), n.getPort());
            for (int i = 0;i<5;i++)
                socket.send(sendPacket);
            System.out.println("packet send to " + n.getIp() + ":" + n.getPort());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException" + n.getIp());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("cant send packet");
        }
    }
}
```

i have stuck there for some days, and try a lot of ways to find where go wrong, help me please.

[node compact info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekIhr.jpg)

this is returned from bootstrap and after bdecoding node compact info

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHG9m.jpg)

[send find_node to bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5fEs.jpg)

[response from bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1FfD.jpg)

[udp packet to node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBQRZ.jpg)

[.pcap file](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13137165/packet.pcap.html)

Comment: Can you post a .pcap (wireshark capture) of the bootstrap find_node, the response and the get neighbor attempts?

Comment: hi and thanks, do i need NAT Traversal? i'm in school wlan@the8472

Comment: I meant the pcap file itself, not screenshots. And if the message to a bootstrap node gets a reply then you probably don't need additional NAT traversal measures to contact other nodes.

Comment: how to send the file to you ? and I found that the protocol of find_node packet i sent to node is UDP but not bt-dht in wireshark, that maybe the problem...altually i implement bencode the packet by hardcoding, like  "d1:t2:" + tid + "1:y1:r1:rd2:id20:5:nodes0:5:token5:" , than turn the string to bytes and send

Comment: I just found something. I fix the socket on port 6881, but when i send the packet, the port changes,

Comment: put it up on some file hoster and update your question with a link to it.

Comment: thankyou for your patience, I have uploaded the file, plz check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some issues by looking at these four packets from the .pcap file

```
110 48.444854   10.3.157.234    82.221.103.244  BT-DHT  134 
...
113 48.844328   82.221.103.244  10.3.157.234    BT-DHT  528 reply=16 nodes 
114 48.911670   10.3.157.234    47.152.12.43    BT-DHT  134 
115 48.912589   10.3.157.234    181.39.146.92   BT-DHT  134
```

---

This is the *find_node* request sent to the bootstrap node: router.utorrent.com [82.221.103.244]

```
Frame 110: 134 bytes on wire (1072 bits), 134 bytes captured (1072 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_1d:89:36 (5c:e0:c5:1d:89:36), Dst: Hangzhou_bf:8e:b0 (d4:61:fe:bf:8e:b0)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.3.157.234, Dst: 82.221.103.244
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 6883, Dst Port: 6881
BitTorrent DHT Protocol
    Transaction ID: 7473
        Key: t
        Value: 7473
    Message type: Request
        Key: y
        Value: q
    Request type: find_node
        Key: q
        Value: find_node
    Request arguments: Dictionary...
        Key: a
        Value: Dictionary...
            id: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
                Key: id
                Value: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
            target: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
                Key: target
                Value: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
```

The node sent both `id` and `target` set to the value: `ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6` so this should be its **node_id**.
This has an minor issue, as the keys in a bencoded dictionary must be sorted, but most implementations will accept the request anyway.
`d1:t2:ts1:y1:q1:q9:find_node1:ad2:id20:.A....T.....P6..6GP.6:target20:.A....T.....P6..6GP.ee`
should be:
`d1:ad2:id20:.A....T.....P6..6GP.6:target20:.A....T.....P6..6GP.e1:q9:find_node1:t2:ts1:y1:qe`

---

This is the response from the bootstrap node:

```
Frame 113: 528 bytes on wire (4224 bits), 528 bytes captured (4224 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: Hangzhou_bf:8e:b0 (d4:61:fe:bf:8e:b0), Dst: IntelCor_1d:89:36 (5c:e0:c5:1d:89:36)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 82.221.103.244, Dst: 10.3.157.234
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 6881, Dst Port: 6883
BitTorrent DHT Protocol
    ip: def983017ed6
        Key: ip
        Value: def983017ed6
    Response values: Dictionary...
        Key: r
        Value: Dictionary...
            id: ebff36697351ff4aec29cdbaabf2fbe3467cc267
                Key: id
                Value: ebff36697351ff4aec29cdbaabf2fbe3467cc267
            nodes: 16
                Key: nodes
                Value: 16 nodes
                Node 1 (id: 2f980c2befa8ae85856bfabd44fb76137c50e39e, IP/Port: 184.148.185.216:43611)
                Node 2 (id: b527925cd9b0f4610904dd2d75aa8c5aa6c900e3, IP/Port: 201.92.140.89:63505)
                Node 3 (id: 454d423032343241433131303030325858587a63, IP/Port: 119.136.154.198:23493)
                Node 4 (id: 4dbe732bad993048936a71ae2c7be49dc9ab24f9, IP/Port: 27.209.68.82:16001)
                Node 5 (id: 39a36bc7f75c494b90395113ab2fd5833c6d684c, IP/Port: 171.239.30.38:1035)
                Node 6 (id: a5ac55cdfdf231bf35e4e68e3b89b5430f0eedd7, IP/Port: 109.154.41.107:58580)
                Node 7 (id: 8f05d55f2129e53c4a1f87b13199b598c479b0aa, IP/Port: 189.78.63.188:27070)
                Node 8 (id: d1bd0a25de085c18d8c45c60f681f7074b9e0458, IP/Port: 95.81.104.30:27196)
                Node 9 (id: 30f0086f8618d7aa5a53b8ac0e3d5b080351fb9a, IP/Port: 70.118.138.155:26085)
                Node 10 (id: dd4797facea363d908b629ce93183c241f08f478, IP/Port: 189.83.128.160:45381)
                Node 11 (id: 0801a40c0e72581bc76e00262350243fc38d21af, IP/Port: 218.210.40.82:31021)
                Node 12 (id: cacf92f943a69abcc24891919d80953b3e70526d, IP/Port: 120.148.25.109:59348)
                Node 13 (id: 3f3834ab54f4215248f0f47d0d0265317d320b48, IP/Port: 189.62.200.109:49307)
                Node 14 (id: fd81b802855925bee2b2ed89134788babe2328bb, IP/Port: 189.152.39.89:43529)
                Node 15 (id: cef348726b9c1278675db1b1da4b605016aab4f8, IP/Port: 189.163.183.249:49937)
                Node 16 (id: 96f24f9a50ee407836fd124932f69e7d49dcad32, IP/Port: 178.77.35.128:34304)
    Transaction ID: 7473
        Key: t
        Value: 7473
    Message type: Response
        Key: y
        Value: r
```

A list with 16 nodes.

---

This is the *find_node* request sent to the first node in the list:
`Node 1 (id: 2f980c2befa8ae85856bfabd44fb76137c50e39e, IP/Port: 184.148.185.216:43611)`

```
Frame 114: 134 bytes on wire (1072 bits), 134 bytes captured (1072 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_1d:89:36 (5c:e0:c5:1d:89:36), Dst: Hangzhou_bf:8e:b0 (d4:61:fe:bf:8e:b0)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.3.157.234, Dst: 47.152.12.43
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 6883, Dst Port: 43611
BitTorrent DHT Protocol
    Transaction ID: 6476
        Key: t
        Value: 6476
    Message type: Request
        Key: y
        Value: q
    Request type: find_node
        Key: q
        Value: find_node
    Request arguments: Dictionary...
        Key: a
        Value: Dictionary...
            id: 2f980c2befa8ae85856bfabd44fb7614364750a6
                Key: id
                Value: 2f980c2befa8ae85856bfabd44fb7614364750a6
            target: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
                Key: target
                Value: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
```

Here are more issues: The `port` and `target` is correct,
but `id` is wrong. It's *queried nodes id* =`2f980c2befa8ae85856bfabd44fb7614364750a6`
instead of *querying nodes id* =`ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6` as it should be.
Nodes will likely not respond to 'id thieves'.
 `IP` is also wrong, instead of `184.148.185.216` it's `47.152.12.43 = 0x2f980c2b` which is the four first bytes in *queried nodes id*. Sending to wrong IP is of course a fatal issue.
The bencoded keys are unsorted.

---

This is the *find_node* request sent to the second node in the list:
`Node 2 (id: b527925cd9b0f4610904dd2d75aa8c5aa6c900e3, IP/Port: 201.92.140.89:63505)`

```
Frame 115: 134 bytes on wire (1072 bits), 134 bytes captured (1072 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_1d:89:36 (5c:e0:c5:1d:89:36), Dst: Hangzhou_bf:8e:b0 (d4:61:fe:bf:8e:b0)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.3.157.234, Dst: 181.39.146.92
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 6883, Dst Port: 63505
BitTorrent DHT Protocol
    Transaction ID: 6f69
        Key: t
        Value: 6f69
    Message type: Request
        Key: y
        Value: q
    Request type: find_node
        Key: q
        Value: find_node
    Request arguments: Dictionary...
        Key: a
        Value: Dictionary...
            id: b527925cd9b0f4610904dd2d75aa8c14364750a6
                Key: id
                Value: b527925cd9b0f4610904dd2d75aa8c14364750a6
            target: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
                Key: target
                Value: ef417ba2c490541a8981d7905036c814364750a6
```

Has the same issues as the first node. All the following requests has the same issues.

Comment: Cool man!Thank you for helping me find some mistakes in my code.I just got some announce_peer requests, do you know some API take the infohash as parameter and return the magedata?I want to build an index map the keyword about file to the magnet link

Comment: There is no easy way to get the metadata from the infohash, other than using a almost fullly functional bittorrent client or using a online service, See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873300/how-to-create-torrent-file-from-magnet-link-using-java/48873710#48873710

Answer (score 0):

> I just found something. I fix the socket on port 6881, but when i send the packet, the port changes

Yes, this is one issue. You should bind a single UDP socket and then keep reusing that socket. As per [BEP 45](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0045.html) it should also be bound to a specific address.

> .pcap file

Packet #2, the response from the bootstrap node contains 16 contacts. The first contact is `id: 0f9c86a1085677f9f1edb519bfc16b626f19fb11, IPv4/Port: 92.255.216.47:29501`

Packet #18 tries to contact `47.216.255.92:29501`

So you are swapping bytes when decoding the IP address. [Contacts](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html#contact-encoding) are encoded in [network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking), i.e. big endian.

You don't need to use string processing for that, [InetAddress.getByAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByAddress(byte%5B%5D)) has an overload that takes byte arrays

Comment: Thank you so much! i have modified the code. now i get some announce_peer requests, do you know some API take the infohash as parameter and return the magedata?I want to build an index map the keyword about file to the magnet link